# add validation and not allow form submit with jQuery word count

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a text area in which can have no more then 100 words. I found a nice indicator script that counts down the words on page, however it still allows the user to submit if users typed in more then 100 words. I need to integrate a validation within. *Note: I am using validate.js in other places.*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#word_count").on('keyup', function() {
        var words = this.value.match(/\S+/g).length;
        if (words > 100) {
            // Split the string on first 100 words and rejoin on spaces
            var trimmed = $(this).val().split(/\s+/, 100).join(" ");
            // Add a space at the end to keep new typing making new words
            $(this).val(trimmed + " ");
        }
        else {
            $('#display_count').text(words);
            $('#word_left').text(100-words);
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: If you're asking about how to use the jQuery Validate plugin, then please at least make an attempt and show us where/how you failed.  I don't see how your word count script would have anything to do with how you would employ some kind of validation.

Comment: Yes. The question was how to integrate validation within this script countdowner I have. Not validate.js I guess I added that in case of a potential conflict scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty hack would be to grab the text from `$('#display_count')`, convert to number and see if it's more than or equal to 100 and stop the form from submitting. Since you're using [**jQuery Validation Plugin**](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) (assumed), you could do:

```
$(".myForm").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
      var total = parseInt($('#display_count').text(), 10);
      if ( total >= 100 ) {
          alert ("Max limit reached");
          return;
      }
      $(form).submit();
  }
});
```

More on [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eL4Ljtmu/)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just add a max length attribute to the text area? Does it meet your requirements?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp

No it does not because count the characters and not the words. But if you apply that script the text is trimmed and takes just the first 100 words.
The line is

```
var trimmed = $(this).val().split(/\s+/, 100).join(" ");
```

where 100 is the limit

Here is my answer

```
 $.validator.addMethod("wordCount", function(value) {
            var words = value.match(/\S+/g).length;
            return words < 100;
        }, 'You can enter max 100 words');

        $("#form").validate({
            rules: {
                textarea : "wordCount"
            }
        });
```

while the html is

```
 <form name="form" id="form" method="get" >
     <textarea name="textarea" ></textarea>
     <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return $('#form').valid()" />
 </form>
```

Comment: `maxlength` would mean maximum number of chars allowed and not words!

Comment: Sorry, slightly confused. Are you suggesting use maxlength still?

Comment: The user cannot write more than 100 words. The max length is not useful

Comment: OK.. what is your proposed answer...  I already had that var trim code in?